# Unchanged Cell after filling a condition in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I want to create a conditional cell formation.

Say Column B has a value that is a live score:

In Column C, I want to create an if condition, like this:

if B>10, then C is YES.

However, as I mentioned, B column as live score, even if B falls below 10 afterward, I want C to remain unchanged. So essentially, I want C to remain at yes, once my live score condition hits.

Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: Hi there @JoshMakan! I understand that you have a changing value in Column B and if it meets a criteria you would like to run some operations on another column. If my understanding of this scenario is correct, then you could easily do this operation with [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) in [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script). Would that be a valid resolution for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Apps Script editor with the code below:

```
function liveScorePass(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var i = 0;
  Logger.log(i);
  while (i == 0){
    Logger.log('B1');
    if (spreadsheet.getRange('B1').getValue() > 10){
      spreadsheet.getRange('C1').setValue("YES");
      Logger.log('C1');
      i = 1;
    }
    else{
      spreadsheet.getRange('C1').setValue("NO");
    }
  }
}

/* OPTIONAL FUNCTION*/

function onOpen(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      ui.createMenu('Live Score Menu')
          .addItem('Reset Script', 'liveScorePass') //creates a menu to start the script again
      .addToUi();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  liveScorePass(); //starts the script whenever you open the spreadsheet.
}
```

It basically checks if your cell `B1` is greater than 10. If it's not, the script keeps running indefinetly, but when it is, the value of `C1` is set to `YES` and `i` is set to 1, breaking away from thw `while` loop, no longer changing the value of `C1` independent of the value of `B1`.

#### Edit

To use it as a function rather than a tab on the toolbar menu, you can just call it as if it were a formula `=LIVESCOREPASS()`. However, this implicates three things:

1. You can't use any `set*()` methods, so you need to adapt you coding, leaving you with this:

```js
 function LIVESCOREPASS(){
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var i = 0;
      Logger.log(i);
      while (i == 0){
        Logger.log('B1');
        if (spreadsheet.getRange('B1').getValue() > 10){
          var result1 = "YES";
          Logger.log('C1');
          i = 1;
          return result1;
        }
        else{
          var result2 = "NO";
          return result2;
        }
      }
    }
```

2. It won't allow changes in arbitrary cells other than the one you're using or its adjacents (not a problem here);
3. Every time you update your referenced cell (`B1`), the function is reset, so you'll lose the fix "`YES`" if it drops to 10 or below.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_a_custom_function) you can find the documentation on Custom Functions.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. how do I incorporate it as a function in the google spreadsheet. It's now coming as a tab. I can't find it as a function.

Comment: I'll update the answer with the code for it, however it won't work, because it autoresets everytime you update `B1`. I can show you how to use it as a function, but then you'll need some other way to do it.